# Getter call not recognised as a statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, getter

I have a singleton:

```
private static MyClass instance;

public static MyClass Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            GameObject go = GameObject.Find("MyClassObject");

            if(go == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Can not found MyClassObject!");
            }

            instance = go.GetComponent<MyClass>();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}

void Awake()
{
    MakePhotoState.Instance;   // 1
}
```

At `1` I'd like to call the `Instance` getter which would create the instance for my singleton. `Awake` is actually a `MonoBehaviour` method (`Unity3D` stuff) but I don't think that's important here.

Code at `1` gives me the following error:

```
error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

whose meaning I understand but it shouldn't apply here - I'm calling (implicitly) the `Instance` getter.

One workaround I can think of would be to assign the result of `1` to a local dummy variable but that's a bad solution IMO.

Is there any way to call `get` explicitly? If not, how do I make the error go away?

Comment: why would you want Instance initialized, when you dont even need to access it?

Comment: Well I do. Why would you say I don't?

Comment: because it doesnt make sense. it would only make sense if you initialize other stuff, that is not related to `instance` in the getter, which would be bad practice and unintuitive

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I've updated my question to show the actual `get` code. It's `Unity` related - I get the instance created by `Unity` there. Is it still bad practice/doesn't make sense?

Comment: i also still dont follow :) why do you need `Instance` initialized, when you dont need to access it? The only case I could imagine is that you need the private `instance` variable initialized. Is that the case?

Comment: I do need to access it. I'm using `Instance` in other classes like this: `MyClass.Instance.SomePublicMethod()`.

Comment: Instance will be initialized, once you access it. did you try your code without your workaround?

Comment: You mean I don't need to initalize that manually as it will get done so later on at the first usage (from some other class)? Well, I've just realized it's unnecessary. It's not even my code, though.

Comment: yes exactly, set a breakpoint in the getter and see that it will be initialized when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property accessors aren't quite the same thing as method calls.  Try moving your init code into a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx), and letting the Instance getter just return the (`private static readonly`) singleton instance.

The plus is that the static constructor will automatically be executed for you before any interaction with that class occurs.

Comment: One caveat, with static constructors and Unity3D: certain calls such as `Resources.Load` are prone to error out if the static constructor is called before a scene is loaded. I sometimes prefer to wait until `Awake` and use lazy initialization so that I'll be sure to avoid that scenario.